# div auto slide fade in/out or ease for better transistion

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a div that auto slides down and loops back up to the top. However the transition from the bottom to the top is very rigid and needs some sort of ease or fade or possibly delay.

I have tried using a fade but was unable to get it to fade properly.

Here is the JsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/pw08cy6g/4/

```js
var scrollDistancePerSecond = 30; // Scroll 50px every second.
var scrollDistancePerAnimationFrame = Math.ceil(scrollDistancePerSecond / 60); // Animate at 60 fps.
var wrapper = document.getElementById('ph0');
autoScroll(wrapper);


function autoScroll(element) {
  if (element.scrollTop < element.scrollHeight) {
    window.requestAnimationFrame(autoScroll.bind(null, element));
    
    if( element.scrollTop === (element.scrollHeight - element.offsetHeight)){
     element.scrollTop = 0
   $("#ph0").stop().fadeOut();
  }else{
    
    element.scrollTop += scrollDistancePerAnimationFrame;
    }
  }
}
```